# Laravel 5.2 Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to deploy a laravel project to a shared hosting platform but it keeps giving me this error 500 -Internal Server Error. It is currently working in my localhost. I have checked other site but with no avail even though .htaccess has been said to be the course but i am yet to figure it out. I have been trying for 5days but have not gotten it.

This is my .htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

If any other file is needed, i would provide. I need to deliver to a client.

Comment: Please check your Apache logs. There should be something in there relating to your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot check the logs ( what would be the prefered way ) you can put this in your code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Simply add it to the index.php of your public folder - if this is not working add it within the bootstrap of your app ( basically the very first thing called ) 
Then open the page and you will see the error.

**Do not forget to remove these lines when the error is resolved**

Usually the problem is missing access rights to the storage folder. If you use Filezilla for example simply rightclick the **storage** folder of your app and select **File permission** Ensure 777 is set and **cascade** it for every file and folder.

Comment: Thanks, this was the error i received when I added the error_reporting(E_ALL)
Notice: Constant LARAVEL_START already defined in /home/ogunsecs/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 3

Comment: Did you change anything in the default setup in order to host it?

Comment: Thank you and have finally gotten it as I changed it back to the default setup which i changed earlier.